# whai it "Err: Failed to expand ARM9 prg?

Tags: multi-function-printer

Err: Failed to expand ARM9 prg. Can someone confirm if I need a new SD card containing the firmware. Got this error displayed on an mfp printer.

Comment: What were you doing when you got this error? Where and when is this error displayed?

Comment: That's the error displayed when I switched on the printer.